# meaning of standard ways of saying in the context of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am studying a family of PDEs depending on a real parameter $\alpha$, say $\alpha \in [0,1]$.  What does it mean that $\alpha = 0$ is a singular limit for the equation? In my case the equation is qualitatively of second order for $\alpha > 0$ and it turns to be of fourth order when $\alpha = 0$; that's all or the expression "singular limit" is telling me more that I already know?

Also, what do "local-" and "non-local-" character mean in the context of PDEs?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically that's all. "Singular limit" means that the equation changes order (or otherwise changes behaviour dramatically) at $\alpha=0$.
2. "Local character" means some quantity at a point depends on the values and derivatives of the relevant quantities at the same point. "Nonlocal" would mean that points at a finite distance can have influence.